# Getting width of a child div with width 100% gives windows width

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        <div id="child1"></div> <!-- UPDATE -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent{
    float:left;
    width:90%;
}

/* UPDATE*/ #parent #child{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}

/* UPDATE*/
/* In a different file*/
#child1{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
```

jQuery:

Say the width of the window is 1000px. So the width of #parent should be 900px. If I try to get the width of the #child1 it should also be 900px. But the below jQuery code returns 1000px.

```
jQuery("#child").width(); //UPDATE: returns 900px as width
jQuery("#child1").width(); //UPDATE: returns 1000px as width
```

I need 900px as result of the above statement.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/F86Jr/ - works fine here. Some other CSS or HTML that you haven't shared must be affecting things. You don't have two elements with `id="child"`, do you?

Comment: Verified that this is calculating the proper dimensions: http://jsfiddle.net/jbayf/

Comment: BTW: Do you use jQuery only for this? Then you better use pure JS: `document.getElementById('parent').offsetWidth`

Comment: @alexP: No I am using jQuery for the whole project.

Comment: Still normal: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/F86Jr/3/